# Microwaves: why do they cook food?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life, microwaves, food

I have looked up several explanations of microwaves and how they work but I am unclear on a few key parts of how they actually make the food hotter.

**How I understand it now:**
In addition to the light and the rotating plate inside the microwave unit there is something called a magnetron that generates microwaves and focuses them at whatever is on the plate.  The nature of microwave waves is that they do not affect glass, some plastics and a few other things like metals which reflect the microwaves.  The microwave wave that is generated by the magnetron enters one of the molecules of the food and “is converted to kinetic energy” (why? How? By what? What effects does that process have? Why does that kinetic energy make the food hotter?)

That’s it.  Can someone please explain to me how the microwave wave makes food hot?

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future, Bob’s answer AND Dipson’s answer were both very useful and explained different aspects of the question.  There was even another answer here that was good and explained more.  Honestly they are both solutions and both answers are good and now some of the comments even seem good but I do not know of a way to mark them both so I will just upvote them all.  This thread is good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The primary mechanism involved with microwave cooking is the interaction between the alternating electric field component of the 2400 Mhz microwave electromagnetic field and the polar molecules of the water content of food. This gives the water molecules rotational kinetic energy. The rotational kinetic energy is then randomized by means of collisions between water molecules, increasing the translational kinetic energy of the molecules. That, in turn, results in an increase in the temperature of the food thus cooking the food.

Its a common misconception that microwave ovens "heat" food. Heat is energy transfer solely due to temperature difference. Microwave ovens don't cook like a conventional oven which uses heat. The energy transfer to the food involved with microwave ovens is work. Namely, the work that the alternating electric field performs on the water molecule dipole.

> Are you saying that the microwaves increase the rotational energy of a
> molecule the wave enters? Why does the microwave increase the
> rotational kinetic energy? I am very curious how microwaves that enter
> a molecule increase that molecule’s rotational energy.

Yes.

There are two ways of looking at it, one using the wave (classical) model and one from the particle (quantum) model.

**Wave Model:**

The diagram below is perhaps a crude way of showing how the electric field component of the electromagnetic wave interacts with a water molecule inducing rotation. The water molecules is a an electric dipole owing to the spacial arrangement of the two hydrogen at one end and one oxygen atom at the other. It is overall electrically neutral, but is positive at one end and negative at the other forming a dipole, as shown.

At the electromagnetic wave propagates past the molecule, the electric field component alternates in polarity. When it does the molecule aligns  itself (rotates) with the field due to the attraction and repulsion forces. That gives the molecules rotational kinetic energy.

**Particle (Photon) Model:**

In the photon (particle) model, the quantum energy of microwave photons is in the range 0.00001 to 0.001 eV which is in the range of energies separating the quantum states of molecular rotation and torsion. So in this model you can view the transfer of microwave electromagnetic energy in the form of photons absorbed by the molecule dipoles causing them to undergo rotation and torsion.

For a more detailed description of the interaction of electromagnetic radiation with matter, check out the following site: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod3.html

Hope this help.

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that the microwaves increase the rotational energy of a molecule the wave enters?  Why does the microwave increase the rotational kinetic energy?

Comment: @fall3n Yes. But I will update my answer to explain how this happens, both from an electromagnetic wave perspective and from the particle (photon) perspective. Please stand by.

Comment: Thank you, please let me know when you do as I am very curious how microwaves that enter a molecule increase that molecule’s rotational energy.

Comment: @fall3n See update to my answer.

Comment: Wow ok that diagram helps.  Perhaps I am missing something obvious So please correct me if I am wrong in my understanding.  The microwave wave is labeled in the diagram as “Alternating Electric Field”. The microwave wave has magnetic poles in the following order from left to right: +-+.  The + poles In the microwave wave attract the - poles of the water molecules, so the molecules rotate so that those poles can be closer. The explanation in this comment is my understanding of the “warming” phenomenon so 1. please tell me if my understanding is correct or not.

Comment: 2. Is it correct that the nature of a microwave is that it has alternating + and - poles throughout? (As shown in the diagram?)

Comment: @fall3n It is a sinusoidal wave. A sinusoidal  wave continuously alternates between  + and -.

Comment: Yes the nature of a sinusoid always wave is that it alternates between + and -, however I have understand microwaves to only be sinusoidal sometimes.  1. Question 1 from two comments ago 2. Are the microwaves produced by microwave units in kitchens always sinusoidal?

Comment: @fall3n 1.Microwaves freely moving through space are electromagnetic waves having two orthogonal components, both sinusoidal, one the electric field the other the magnetic field. See the images in this link: https://www.google.com/search?q=electromagnetic+wave+images&oq=&aqs=chrome.0.69i59i450l8.514293917j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: 2. In the microwave oven the electromagnetic waves do not propagate freely as they do in space since they reflect off of the walls of the oven. This can result in constructive and destructive interference, standing waves, etc. so that they may not be sinusoidal. But the food is on a rotating table so that there is relative motion between the electric field and the water molecules and even out the cooking process

Comment: The net effect is that the water molecules are subjected to changing electric fields causing rotation. In this respect my drawing was an oversimplification (I did say it was crude) just to give you the general idea. It was not meant to be taken literally.

Comment: Oh I think I understand now, tell me if I am wrong please: the microwaves that are generated move quickly past the water molecules in the food.  The moving wave means a moving + pole followed by a moving - pole, and so on repeating.  These poles from the wave temporarily attract the opposite pole in the water molecule and since the wave is moving, the water molecule rotates in order to move it’s pole closer to the opposite pole on the wave.  That rotation of the water molecule generates friction and so heat making the food hotter.  Please confirm if that Description is correct.

Comment: @fall3n Essentially yes. But instead of thinking in terms of moving "poles" think in terms of the change in the direction of the electric field as the wave moves past the molecules. And don't think in terms of "generating friction" and "heating" the food. The molecules acquire rotational kinetic energy due to work by the field. When they collide with other molecules the rotational kinetic is randomized to increase the average translational kinetic energy of the molecules. That equates to a temperature rise of the food causing it to cook.

Comment: Bob, thank you so much.  I marked your answer as the solution so you will get credit for all the help you gave me.

Comment: @fall3n Thank you for that

Answer (score 4):

When you start cooking, the **magnetron** takes **electricity** from the power outlet and converts it into high-powered, **radio waves**. The **magnetron** blasts these waves into the food compartment. The food sits on a turntable, spinning slowly round so the microwaves cook it evenly. The microwaves bounce back and forth off the reflective metal walls of the food compartment, just like light bounces off a mirror. **When the microwaves reach the food itself, they don't simply bounce off. Just as radio waves can pass straight through the walls of your house, so microwaves penetrate inside the food. As they travel through it, they make the molecules inside it vibrate more quickly.** Vibrating molecules makes it hot so, the faster the molecules vibrate, the hotter the food becomes. Thus the microwaves pass their energy onto the molecules in the food, rapidly heating it up.

In simple terms. ****Microwave** cook food by generating **kinetic energy** between the molecules of the food.**

Comment: Re, "vibrating molecules" and "inter-molecular friction." There's no friction. Rather, the internal kinetic energy ("vibrating molecules") of a substance is what _defines_ its temperature. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperature#Microscopic_statistical_mechanical_scale

Comment: @SolomonSlow It sounds like you are saying that molecular vibration IS what makes things hot.  Ok, that makes sense, but why does a microwave cause a molecule to vibrate?

Comment: @fall3n I'm not saying that molecular vibration _makes_ things hot, I'm saying that it's the very _definition_ of "hot." When you say that something is hot, you are saying that its molecules, on average, have relatively high kinetic energy. As for the mechanism at work in a microwave oven, I'm sorry but I don't think I am capable of giving you a better explanation than the ones that already are here in the answers.

Comment: Microwaves don't make molecules vibrate. They make them rotate. The vibration energy mode involves energy levels  above that of microwaves. Infrared radiation makes molecules.

Comment: @SolomonSlow ok thanks for your contribution, I feel that I understand this process a little more now.  I am still unclear as to exactly how microwave waves “increase” rotational energy of molecules they enter but hopefully someone will explain that interesting answer.